# Тире или двоеточие в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

У меня снова проблемы с «тире или двоеточием», сколько не читал правила на эту тему.
Тире или двоеточие в следующем предложении?

> «Уж лучше я сосредоточусь на своей сфере (-) случае и неопределенности.»

Answer (score 2):

[Д.Э.Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=316)  При обособлении **приложений** вместо запятой употребляется **тире**:

1) ***если перед приложением можно вставить слова "а именно" (без изменения смысла)***:

В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно — огонь квартиры Серафимы (Ж. Г.)...

2) ***перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение***:

Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину.

**У Вас как раз дающее разъяснение приложение, находящееся в конце предложения. Поэтому ставим ТИРЕ.**

Answer (score 1):

**Уж лучше я сосредоточусь на своей сфере (какой именно?) — на случае и неопределенности.**

Это **пояснительная** конструкция, так как раскрывается значение местоимения ***своей***. В этом случае ставится **тире** (двоеточие **допускается** при определенных условиях).

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

**При отсутствии пояснительного союза** вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто **ставится тире:** Иногда что-нибудь хочется сделать — почитать (Г.); Эти птицы [стенолазы] добывают свой корм исключительно в воздухе — питаются летающими насекомыми; Он обладает особой способностью — всё делать вовремя; Разговор шёл один — о погоде;

**Возможна также постановка двоеточия** (чтобы избежать двух тире): Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений — водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами.

**Примечание** (о стилистике предложения)

Обособленный член должен иметь ясную семантику, поэтому желательно повторить предлог НА. Но тогда возможно сходство с сочетанием *на случай*.

Поэтому возможно такое редактирование: *Уж лучше я сосредоточусь на своей сфере — на случайности (непредсказуемости, непредвиденности) и неопределенности.*